# How to compile in place with gulp (pipe to src dir)

Tags: gulp

How can I compile all files from specified folders (and its sub-folders) in place?

E.g. in case of TypeScript to JavaScript compilation:

[before]

```
/
/src
/src/app.ts
/lib
/lib/lib.ts
```

[after]

```
/
/src
/src/app.ts
/src/app.js
/lib
/lib/lib.ts
/lib/lib.js
```

- Without specifying 2 separate tasks.

Comment: I think this thread deserve better title (to be searchable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `dest` directory to the same as the `src`:

```
gulp.src('./**/*')
  .pipe(something)
  .pipe(or)
  .pipe(other)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```